# Performing Operation on Byte Array by segments

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, arrays

What would be the best and simplest way to implement some operation work on byte array when you need to work segment by segment from that array. For example, segment size is 4096 bytes and you need to perform any operation but using segments of 4096 bytes. Return value should again be byte array, and I am looking on some way to avoid alot of copying into new arrays if possible. Also, it must work on .net 3.0

Comment: It sounds like you need to work 'in-place' i.e. the function you write needs to be passed the byte array, and inside that function you perform the byte operations to modify the elements of the array. What sort of byte operation is being performed?

Comment: I need to perform AES encryption on 4k bytes. I have byte array and I need to produce encrypted byte array, but encrypted segment by segment

Comment: in that case I think you can work in-place then. The ciphertext (output) of AES will be the same size as the plaintext (input) assuming the number of total bytes is a multiple of the block size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines? Your question is pretty generic...

```
const int SEGMENT_SIZE = 4096;
int segment, i;

f(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
{
  byte[] output = new byte[length];

  // TODO: implement

  return output;
}

segment = 0;
while(segment * SEGMENT_SIZE < buffer.Length)
{
    output = f(buffer, segment * SEGMENT_SIZE, SEGMENT_SIZE);
    segment++;
}
```

Output without segments:

```
g(byte[] src, byte[] dst, int srcOffset, int dstOffset, int length)
{
  // TODO: implement process from src[srcOffset + i] to dst[dstOffset + i]

  // no return, has side-effect on dst
}


outputBuffer = new byte[inputBuffer.Length];
segment = 0;
while(segment * SEGMENT_SIZE < inputBuffer.Length)
{
    g(inputBuffer, outputBuffer, segment * SEGMENT_SIZE, segment * SEGMENT_SIZE, SEGMENT_SIZE);
    segment++;
}
```

AES encryption maintains the size of the blocks, so data will be aligned block-by-block. Pay attention to padding, last segment might be partial. Use the right padding, I've had a hard time to get it working because of a bad padding. Also make sure you can have 4096 byte blocks... IIRC you should use 2 blocks of 256 bytes each. Either way, you'll have to fiddle with values quite a lot! Good luck :)

Comment: Exactly that! Thanks! I had on my mind alot of copying into new smaller arrays, I was missing exactly this. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you feel so inclined.

Comment: Still, this would not return one byte array but ByteArray.Length/Segment single byte arrays, right?

Comment: You can easily modify it to write into an output array.

Comment: Thanks for quick and nice solution, I would upvote if I had enough reputation, but I marked as solution.